# HTML select not working with Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am having trouble setting up HTML select in Meteor.
I am using the Materialize.css package for styling.

This is the template for the select box :

```
<div class="input-field col l6 s12">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        {{#each getCategories}}
            <option value="1">{{category_name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</div>
```

`getCategories` is a function that returns the names of all the categories. I need to use this function's result to populate a select box.
The problem is, the data sometimes gets loaded into the select box - sometimes it does not.
Sometimes the values in the select disappear on page refresh. At the same time a dropdown I am using for the same is working perfectly.

Here is the code of the dropdown :

```
<div class="col l6">
    <a class='dropdown-button btn'  data-activates='dropdown1'>Categories</a>
    <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
        {{#each getCategories}}
            <li><a>{{category_name}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul> 
</div>
```

The dropdown works perfectly. I don't know what is wrong with my select.

The code used to initialize the select box :

```
Template.posts.rendered = function() {
  $('#content').ckeditor();
  $('select').material_select();
  $('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
     inDuration: 300,
     outDuration: 225,
     constrain_width: true, 
     hover: true, 
     gutter: 0, 
     belowOrigin: true 
  });
};
```

Why is my `<select>` template behaving weirdly when the same logic with a dropdown works?

Comment: can you post `getCategories` helper code and are you sure the data that youu want is existed in ckient? Can you post your publishh and suscribe code too

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh If I had had to review your edit, I would have rejected it because it barely improved a post that had many more issues. Please only make edits that thoroughly improve all lacking aspects of a post (noise, formatting, spelling, ...). Otherwise you are wasting the reviewers time.

Comment: If you are using `iron:router` make sure you do a `waitOn()` for your subscriptions inside this route. I'm sure your helper `getCategories()` is an empty array at the time of the loading.

Comment: getCategories() is empty when the select-box is initialized. At the same time the drop-down displaying the data using same function is working perfectly. I am using iron:router. let me try waitOn(). Thank you.